# SwiftUI question - cannot be resolved without a contextual type

Tags: xcode, swiftui

Reference to member 'horizontal' cannot be resolved without a contextual type

I just added a very simple coding but end up stuck here for hours

```
.padding(.horizontal.20)
```

and error pops up

wanna know how to fix it

Comment: You've got a typo it should be `.padding(.horizontal, 20)` (with a comma not a period)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code in your question is copy/pasted from your actual code then there is a typo.

This...

```
.padding(.horizontal.20)
```

Should be...

```
.padding(.horizontal, 20)
```

It is using the API... https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/padding(_:_:)

This takes the `Edges` and the `distance`. As two separate parameters.